# Is there a way to find out when my external hard drive was unplugged?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, event-viewer

My two external hard drives were manually unplugged from my Windows 10 laptop last night, presumably by my roommate, either that or I'm losing my mind/sleepwalking. I'm really curious and I searched through Event Viewer looking for some kind of sign, but I can't find it. Where would I find this event of a USB device being unplugged? Thanks.

Comment: Probably (a) if the drives are noisy, otherwise (b)(i). Or do you not mean *physically* unplugged?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the Windows Event Logs with a third-party tool such as Nirsoft's free [FullEventLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/fulleventlogview/), to get a flat view of the numerous separate logs.

[image: FullEventLogView Search]

The image above shows the result of a search in *FullEventLogView* for the string *usb*, for *all* events in the last two days.

- Click on *Options* to select *Advanced Options*.
- Check all *Event Levels*.
- Set the time period for the search.
- Select *Show only events with the specified event description strings,* and *Search in the full description string*.
- Click *OK*.
- Click the *Refresh* button or press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the query again.

Comment: I tried FullEventLogView. Cool program but unfortunately there's nothing I can find that relates to the devices being unplugged no matter how I search it, even just going through the events unfiltered. There are logs of me plugging them in and accessing them this morning, but nothing else in the last day that I can find. The thing is, whether it was me that unplugged them or not, I know I was accessing data on them last night, so they definitely got unplugged sometime over the last 12 hours and yet I can't find it. Maybe the system just doesn't log those events?

Comment: @tonyd1234 maybe the drive was not plugged in yesterday